# Java: How to execute an XPath query on a node

Tags: java, xpath, nodes, xpathnodeiterator

So I'm reading from an XML file with many layers of nesting in Java using xPath.

At the moment I have a method that takes the path to XML file and a xpath query as parameters, and returns a NodeIterator.

Then I iterate through those node, and for some of the nodes (if their name matches) I need to execute another query on them and get a NodeIterator of their children etc

Is it possible to have a function with 2 parameters, one an already existing Node and the other an xPath query to execute on that Node?

So replacing:`NodeIterator ni = XPathAPI.selectNodeIterator(document,xpathQuery);`
With some like : `NodeIterator ni2 = xPathAPI.selectNodeIterator(parentNode, query);`

I've searched on the internet and I can't find any examples, and I'm not sure what the syntax to do the above would be, or if it's even possible?

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: is there any particular reason for you to use XPathAPI?.  javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression.evaluate() is able to do what you want by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably your XPathAPI class is the Apache/Xalan org.apache.xpath.XPathAPI?

In that case, what's wrong with

```
static NodeIterator selectNodeIterator(Node contextNode, java.lang.String str)
```

It seems to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Yes, that's exactley what I was looking for - THANKS!